# Cannot seem to access certain data with bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access the following data that has been parsed by csv-parser in node.js but I'm having difficulty accessing First Name for some reason. I can access every other row using bracket notation but for some reason not that one. I access the others with `row['Last Name']` but when I do `row['First Name']` it comes back as undefined? Any ideas?

```
{
  'First Name': 'Bobby',
  'Last Name': 'Taylor',
  'Home Phone': '3661773140',
  'Mobile Phone': '3955413767',
  'Street Address': '8001 NW Cedar St',
  City: 'Urbandale',
  State: 'IA',
  Zip: '50310',
  'Date of Birth': '4/12/1973'
}
```

Comment: It should work. Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Make sure the spaces and upper/lower case match correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad hidden character in your JSON.

This is how it is coming

[image: See image]

I cleaned up your object for you and here is a demo of it working -

```js
var obj = {
 'First Name': 'Bobby',
 'Last Name': 'Taylor',
 'Home Phone': '3661773140',
 'Mobile Phone': '3955413767',
 'Street Address': '8001 NW Cedar St',
 City: 'Urbandale',
 State: 'IA',
 Zip: '50310',
 'Date of Birth': '4/12/1973'
}

console.log(obj['First Name'])
```

Comment: What was the hidden character? How can I account for that, and how did you find that out?

Comment: I copied pasted your JSON object into Chrome Devtools and found it out

Comment: There is some special character before "First Name" which was causing the key to become something else. So i deleted that special character and it is working now.

Comment: So this is coming back from a database, is there a way I can eliminate hidden characters with javascript?

Comment: I'd fix whatever put that character in the first place.

Comment: I would clean up the database if I were you. But you can probably use a regex to clean up the keys and values.

Comment: input.replace(/\W/g, ''), where input is a string

Comment: So this is just test data for a coding exercise, I'm sure this is a gotcha type problem. I wonder if there is a way to eliminate the problem....

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please consider marking this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: @MukundGoel where did you find the JSON object to copy/paste that included the hidden character?

Comment: I marked it as correct but I'm not getting the same results you were in dev tools. Can you walk me through that?

Comment: @testersontesting Maybe he was just guessing.  It is actually pretty common when parsing spreadsheets to get weird random characters in there.  Did your code actually work after stripping non-word characters using that replace?

Comment: I copy pasted your object into devtools, put it in some variable (obj), then I did Object.keys(obj), then it came up.

Comment: This seems to be what is happening https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-tale-about-feff-the-invisible-character-cd25cd4630e7/

Comment: @user120242 so I'm not exactly sure how to use that replace properly.....

Comment: I know this is common for csv files, as I've been bitten by this one a lot working with csvs that have foreign languages in them, but I can't for the life of me find that invisible character.  I've gone as far as to scan the source of the page and still can't find it.

Comment: @testersontesting `var keyFixedObj = Object.keys(row).reduce( (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc||{}, { [key.replace(/\W/g, '')]: row[key] }) );`

Comment: @user120242 I found the hidden character you cannot copy and paste my object you have to go in and copy it from the editor screen I think. And that was indeed the problem also this worked for me .pipe(csv({mapHeaders: ({ header }) => header.replace(/\W/g, '')}))

Comment: Just an fyi for anyone happening upon this and are dealing with foreign languages.  The regex replace above won't work for special characters like accents or Chinese, Arabic.  You'll have to find a library to handle unicode or specifically filter out invalid characters sneaking into your files.